# Files with information obtained from spying on people

Tags: phrase-requests, adjectives

Suppose you're living in an oppressive (English-speaking) regime, where intelligence agencies keep files on people with information garnered from informants who interact with them or agents who follow them around.

What verbless adjective-phrase could we use to describe these files?

I'm looking for an adjective-phrase, so I could say these are "[something] files"

Comment: "secret files".."confidential dossier". You should ask ask one of the attendees at the secret policeman's other ball.

Comment: @Cascabel: The fact that a file is secret doesn't say much about what's in it. Also, obviously these files would be secret to some extent.

Comment: @einpoklum....I often think and write out loud. My comments are to help me, and you to figure out a good reply. It is a cooperative effort.

Comment: @Cascabel: Fair enough... please take my comment in the same spirit then :-)

Comment: Here is the issue: people living under such a regime would find it to be normal practice; hence,  it becomes a police matter. If you are criticizing it from the outside, it would have a different description

Comment: surveillance files

Comment: The terms that people would use for such a thing are likely to be country-specific: something like *XYZ dossier* or *XYZ file*, where *XYZ* is the name (possibly an abbreviation) of the government entity that keeps these records.

Comment: Probably there is no such phrase for the obvious reason that a secret service will not want it to get out that such files exist.  So they might call them something like 'keyhole files' (possibly too obvious) or 'portrait files'.

Comment: @Cascabel: The term doesn't have to be very "judgemental".

Comment: See the bottom half of my edit....

Answer (score 5):

***dossier***

> a set of papers containing information about a person, often a criminal, or on any subject:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dossier)

Ex

> The secret service probably has a dossier on all of us.

Confidential information might be redacted on an official report to protect the identity of the informer.

Confidential Informants are also called CI in the USA.

> A confidential informant (CI)1 is defined as an individual requiring anonymity who provides useful information, directed assistance, or both, that enhances criminal investigations and furthers the mission of the agency, usually in exchange for financial or other consideration. Individuals who serve as witnesses or citizens who provide information regarding criminal activity are generally not considered CIs. This distinction is based in part on the fact that CI arrangements involve the development of a relationship between the individual and the agency that focuses on the trading of information for some form of payment, to include prosecutorial consideration.Although CIs can provide investigators with specific information that is not available from other sources, it must be remembered that CIs are often criminals.

So maybe ***CI Files***?

Comment: This is not so bad, as a _noun_, but I'm looking for an adjective-phrase, so I could say these are  "[something] files".

Comment: I was actually in the middle of that when you pinged me...please give me a few moments to collect my thoughts...txs

Comment: @einpoklum How about “surveillance files”?

Comment: @jwpfox: Make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *“[surveillance files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance)"*.

Comment: Surveillance is a good adjective. If the OP is not too attached to the word "files", then "surveillance reports" might be better as it more clearly explains that the documents are the result of surveillance (rather than concerning surveillance in some other way).